# Can the dbo.ELMAH_Error.AllXml column type be changed to Sql Server XML column type?

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, elmah

I have run a quick test of changing the AllXml column of dbo.ELMAH_Error to XML type.  Logging inserts and the standard log viewer still function.

This has the benefit of allowing me to create indexes on the AllXml column.  However, I am concerned that this may cause an incompatibility with other software that may work in conjunction with ELMAH.

What are the ramifications of doing this?

Comment: You could index `AllXml` by creating a hacky [indexed view](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6620076/772086). What other software interacts with Elmah? That is, what incompatibility are you worried about? Looking at Elmah itself: Elmah is open source, so you could open up the [source code](http://elmah.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/Elmah/SQLServer.sql) to find objects that are affected by changing the data type of `AllXml` (e.g., `dbo.ELMAH_LogError`.)

Comment: http://elmahr.apphb.com/ or https://github.com/wasphub/RElmah as examples.